# Skipped Jobs because of DST

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, jobs, dst, timertask

I have to schedule a few jobs using Java Timer using JDK1.4 without using any third-party API.

If the [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) change is from 2 am to 3 am , what should be the expected behavior for Jobs scheduled between the DST transition time i.e 2 am and 3 am?

1. Should the jobs be simply ignored as the time between 2 am and 3 am never appears on the clock
2. Should they be run immediately at 3 am.
3. Any other expected behavior ?

I think that many Enterprise applications cannot afford to skip the jobs. How should one proceed ?

Answer (score 3):

Don't store/run/etc. anything using DST.  It's... difficult to maintain.

## UTC

Store all dates in the database in [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).  Perform all time calculations in UTC.  Maintain a single standard non-changing time measurement for all business processes.  Only when displaying a result to a user (showing on a screen, printing on a report, etc.) do you then localize the time to whatever that user would expect.

Basically consider all back-end logic to be in UTC, and at the interface level there would be a kind of translation layer between localized time and "system" time.

Comment: To use UTC and translate to time zones as suggested here in this correct answer, it's best to use either Joda-Time or the java.time package in Java 8. Avoid the java.util.Date/.Calendar classes.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by David](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27603901/642706) is correct.

## `ScheduledExecutorService`

In addition, I suggest using the [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) rather than Timer.

Be sure to read up on including all the JavaDoc. Search StackOverflow to find discussion and example code. Specifically you must trap for all Exceptions or else the service will halt.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.However i have already mentioned that i have to use Java 1.4 and ScheduledExecutorService is available from 1.5.